# How to add controls to tableview cell programatically only once

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
override func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell    {let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
 let customerNameLabel = UILabel()
 customerNameLabel.frame = CGRect (x: 10, y: 5, width: 150, height: 40)
 customerNameLabel.textColor = .black
 customerNameLabel.text = "Customer Name\ (indexPath.row)"
 cell.contentView.addSubview(customerNameLabel)
 return cell      
}
```

While trying to add label to cell it is adding number of times even while scrolling the tableView but I need to add label only once and reuse it

Comment: `cell.contentView.addSubview(customerNameLabel)` this  will keep on adding labels whenever the cell is reused. So you should first check if label already exist or not

Comment: I think best way is subclass UITableViewCell and override init

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom UITableViewCell and add your label to it.

Because in the code you provided you will be adding a UILabel() to the cell every time the cell is reused.

Answer (score 1):

You need create a subclass for `UITableViewCell`

- If you load your cell from xib file, override `awakeFromNib` and add your label to cell inside `awakeFromNib` method.
- If you create your cell programmatically, override `init(style: UITableViewStyle)` and add your label to cell inside `init(style: UITableViewStyle)` method.

Answer (score 0):

That is Because TableView will call the `cellForRowAt` everytime you scroll or reload the tableView.
Either you subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a label there or you have to remove the label every time before adding it.

Comment: how can we remove label everytime

Comment: you can add tag to the label and then get the label with viewWithTag method and remove it before adding again.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the reusable behavior of `UITableViewCell`, the label is added multiple time in a single cell because the cell is being reused if you want to add a single label on the cell you have to check first if it already added.

What we are frequently used:

1) We make the .xib of a cell and reuse it:

2) We make the cell in the storyboard and give the specific identifier to cell and reuse it:

3) You can check the label is already added:

```
var customerNameLabel:UILable? = nil
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell                                            {let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) {
if customerNameLabel == nil {
    customerNameLabel = UILabel()
    customerNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 150, height: 40)
    customerNameLabel.textColor = .black
    cell.contentView.addSubview(customerNameLabel)
}
    customerNameLabel.text = "Customer Name\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell                                                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several simple steps:

1. Subclass UITableViewCell.
2. Add the label to contentView inside `awakeFromNib` (override this method) if you load from nib **OR** `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` (override this method) if you generate the cell programmatically. Alternatively you can set cell's layout in Storyboard of nib itself.
3. In `tableView:cellForRow` set the label's text to whatever you want.